# Can't start Liferay tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to start Liferay tomcat server on Ubuntu 14.04.
To install Liferay 6.1.1, I used the following tutoriel:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uLWkqCg6kg

However, I couldn't start the tomcat server. I got ERROR:

```
10:19:23,067 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][MainServlet:1224] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

.
.
.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutSetImpl.getColorScheme(LayoutSetImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl.getColorScheme(LayoutImpl.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.ThemeServicePreAction.servicePre(ThemeServicePreAction.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.ThemeServicePreAction.run(ThemeServicePreAction.java:44)
    ... 111 more
juil. 06, 2014 10:19:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Impossible de compiler la classe pour la JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 176 in the generated java file
The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
.
.
.
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved.

Comment: I would check the JAVA_HOME first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the tutorial says that you should install OpenJDK. **That is not true, Liferay works well only on Sun/Oracle Java**. My guess is that this is the cause of the problem.
There are a lot of tutorials about how to install Oracle Java on Ubuntu, check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux) for example.

Secondly this tutorial says about 6.1.2 version and you are trying to install 6.1.1. That's also quite important as Java 7 is supported exclusively since 6.1.2 (check James Falkner's [blog post](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/new-release-liferay-portal-6-1-ce-ga3)). For 6.1.1 you should use Java 6.

Hope that helps,
KG

Comment: Hey KALLEL, is my answer correct? You haven't marked it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you want to run your portlet on Java 8.

Follow steps

Steps to fix:-

1.Go to Lib folder of Liferay Tomcat .

2.Replace :- ecj-3.7.2.jar with ecj-4.4.2.

3.Restart the Server.